# Is it possible to check Microsoft Exchange mail from Gmail?

Tags: gmail

My company mail is set up using Microsoft Exchange Server. Is it possible to check/import such emails into my Gmail account?

Comment: What email client do you use? Outlook? OWA?

Comment: @tims I use gmail web application directly

Answer (score 19):

If your admin has enabled it, you can connect to Exchange as a POP3 server. Otherwise, you have to use Outlook to tell Exchange to forward your mail to a Gmail account. Gmail can't ask Exchange directly using Exchange’s own protocols.

Comment: Gmail doesn't support IMAP as a client as far as I know.

Comment: @Nifle - you are right, updated.

Comment: If I use Outlook for forward the email, then what I did with the messages like labeling, read/unread/remove ect. won't be synced with exchange server and that results a mess for me I'm afraid.

Comment: @Nam - Them's your options. Take em or leave em.

Comment: I know Joel. If you don't want to receive feedback, then you won't get no further from me except this last one - I always see the sender is myself in gmail :)

Answer (score 4):

- Create a new server-side rule.
- Set the condition to "All Messages"
- Set the action to "Redirect To" and add your gmail address.

Using Redirect-To, and not Forward-To, preserves the original sender's information.

Comment: That's what I tried originally, but nothing gets through. Does it work for you? Perhaps our Exchange admins have something set up strange.

Comment: My current employer blocks the ability to do this

Answer (score 2):

You can set up a virtual instance on AWS that's always connected to the internet. The security group must be configured to allow external inbound ports for POP3S and SMTPS.

Then install [DavMail](http://davmail.sf.net) on it to [serve as a standard gateway](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-a-davmail-exchange-gateway-on-a-debian-7-vps) to your Microsoft Exchange Server.

The sticky part is you have to configure a CA trusted cert on there, as Gmail does not support self-signed certs.

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score -2):

It is possible to import an account to Gmail. Settings -> Import mails and contact. POP3 must be enabled on the Exchange and settings (port etc.) must be confirmed.

Comment: This information is already provided in [a different answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/14520/354).