# Does Gmail support OAuth2 to check mails form a Microsoft Exchange server?

Tags: gmail, microsoft-account

My question is quite similar to the one posed some time ago:
[Is it possible to check Microsoft Exchange mail from Gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/14519/is-it-possible-to-check-microsoft-exchange-mail-from-gmail)
What’s new is that  Microsoft Exchange does not support POP3 authentication anymore. More recently, someone seems to have had my same problem and is still waiting for an answer: https://www.reddit.com/r/GMail/comments/nej1yg/can_i_route_my_outlook_email_through_my_gmail/

Shortly, my institution mail was recently migrated to Microsoft Exchange Server and I would like to check/import such emails into my Gmail account.
Following the standard procedure to import email into Gmail 
Settings > All Settings > Accounts and Import > Check mail from other accounts: Add another email address
 
I am offered only the possibility to import email from another (non Gmail) POP3 account and not OAUTH2. If I blindly proceed with the POP3 option and set

- POP Server: outlook.office365.com
- Port: 993

The import obviously fails. Does anybody know a way to circumvent this problem or if there is another way to configure OAUTH2 method in Gmail?
I tried setting up a forward rule, but it does not provide the whole functionality I would need; moreover, this solution is discouraged by our institution. Thank you in advance.

Comment: As of July 28, 2022 we are also experiencing this problem. It seems Microsoft has disabled Basic Authentication for POP3 / IMAP. We have yet to find a way to enable it again. Clients like GMail will not be able to authenticate.

Answer (score 1):

#### Can be temporarily restored

It can be re-enabled by an Exchange Admin up to and including December 2022 using MS Exchange's self-service diagnostic.

---

#### Basic Authentication Deprecation Exchange

Microsoft has been planning for some time to disable basic authentication. The original target was the second half of 2021.

In [February 2021 Microsoft](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/basic-authentication-and-exchange-online-february-2021-update/ba-p/2111904) indicated that the pandemic and "the effect it has on priorities" moved it to postpone disabling Basic Auth for protocols **in active use** while extending the scope of the program to include Exchange Web Services (EWS), Exchange ActiveSync (EAS), `POP`, `IMAP`, Remote PowerShell, MAPI, RPC, SMTP AUTH and OAB.

---

#### High Level View

**Source:**
*Basic Authentication Deprecation in Exchange Online* <sup>[[Sept  2022 Update]](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/basic-authentication-deprecation-in-exchange-online-september/ba-p/3609437)</sup>

**Initial Shutdown**

- October 1, 2022 Microsoft will start to randomly select tenants and disable basic authentication access for MAPI, RPC, OAB, EWS, `POP`, `IMAP`, EAS and Remote PowerShell.

**Temporary Re-Enablement (Grace Period)**

- after October 1, customers will be able to re-enable it for any protocols they need, once per protocol<sup>[footnote 1]</sup> via the self-service diagnostic.

**Permanent Shutdown**

- Re-enabled protocols will work until December 2022. In January 2023, these protocols will be permanently disabled.

---

<sup>1</sup>  The peculiar use of the words "once per protocol" in the [Release](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/basic-authentication-deprecation-in-exchange-online-september/ba-p/3609437) suggests to me if, during the grace period, you disable a protocol after re-enabling it, you will not be able to re-enable it and it will remain disabled. i.e. Cannot toggle `on` then `off` then `on`